# HTML page formatting with DIV tags

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm really struggling with layout issues surrounding DIV tags and how the elements are presented during design time. I could really use a visual tool that would help.

Is there an open source application that will allow me to develop HTML pages with DIV tags similar to how DreamWeaver worked?

I'm essentially trying to place a few graphing elements on a page that was previously designed but am struggling with positioning...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span> Dashboard
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span> Orders
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="users"></span> Customers
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span> Reports
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="layers"></span> Integrations
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom"></div>


      <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 780px; height: 400px;"></div>

      *********How to center guages???***********
      <div id="chart_guage" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>


      <h2>User Scores</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>Lorem</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>dolor</td>
              <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,002</td>
              <td>amet</td>
              <td>consectetur</td>
              <td>adipiscing</td>
              <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,015</td>
              <td>sodales</td>
              <td>ligula</td>
              <td>in</td>
              <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet to provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: In this particular case I'm looking to move the "chart_guage to the bottom center of the "barchart_material".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up finding a solution by adding an additional table and adding the elements within the table.

However the solution to my original problem I was looking for was to add margin tags to the  tags.. **margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto**

```
      <div class="table-responsive table-borderless">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div id="chart_guage1" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div></td>
          <td><div id="chart_guage2" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div></td>
          <td><div id="chart_guage3" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div></td>
          <td><div id="chart_guage4" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div></td>
          <td><div id="chart_guage5" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span> Dashboard
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span> Orders
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="users"></span> Customers
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span> Reports
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="layers"></span> Integrations
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom"></div>


      <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 780px; height: 400px;"></div>

      *********How to center guages???***********
      <div id="chart_guage" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>


      <h2>User Scores</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Player</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>Lorem</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>dolor</td>
              <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,002</td>
              <td>amet</td>
              <td>consectetur</td>
              <td>adipiscing</td>
              <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,015</td>
              <td>sodales</td>
              <td>ligula</td>
              <td>in</td>
              <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```